# What is this tree? Southern Missouri in mid April

Tags: trees, flowers

I was told we have flowering pink dogwoods, but these flowers only have reddish/pinkish tips and are yellowish whitish. The tree bloomed much later than the other local white dogwoods did, and these trees are keeping their flowers for much longer as well. What sort of tree is this? Is it actually a dogwood? Is it nutrient deficient or diseased?[image][image]
[image]

Comment: It does look like a dogwood of some sort. Will let someone else weigh in on the species / variety.

Answer (score 1):

Dogwood, very common in southern MO where I am familiar around Bransen. Natives are white, pink would have been planted.